# Unique_ptr game state vs shared_ptr game state

Tags: c++, state, game-state

I have this (typical) base class:

```
class GameState
{
 public:
    GameState(){}
    GameState(GameState&& other) = default;
    GameState& operator=(GameState&& other) = default;
    virtual ~GameState() {}

    virtual int getStateID         ()const = 0;

    virtual bool onEnter           ()      = 0;
    virtual bool onExit            ()      = 0;

    virtual void update (Game& game)       = 0;
    virtual void draw              ()      = 0;

    virtual void shutDown          ()      = 0;
}
```

And this is a state inherited from GameState base class:

```
class gGameStateSplash : public GameState
{
    static bool firstSplash;
    int msplashID;
    uint32_t splashStart;
public:
    gGameStateSplash     () :GameState(), msplashID(SPLASH), splashStart(0) {}
    gGameStateSplash(gGameStateSplash&& other)
    {
        firstSplash = std::move(other.firstSplash);
        msplashID   = std::move(other.msplashID);
        splashStart = std::move(other.splashStart);
    }

    gGameStateSplash& operator=(gGameStateSplash&& other)
    {
        firstSplash = other.firstSplash;
        msplashID   = other.msplashID;
        splashStart = other.splashStart;
        return *this;
    }
    ~gGameStateSplash    ()                                                 {}

    int getStateID       ()const override { return msplashID; }

    bool onEnter         ()override;
    bool onExit          ()override;

    void update(Game& game)override;
    void draw            ()override;

   void shutDown         ()override;
};
```

And this 'GameStateMachine' which use states inherited from GameState:

```
class GameState;
class Game;

class GameStateMachine
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>>mvGameStates;

public:
    GameStateMachine():mvGameStates(){}
    GameStateMachine(GameStateMachine&& other){ mvGameStates = std::move(other.mvGameStates);}
    GameStateMachine& operator=(GameStateMachine&& other) { mvGameStates = std::move(other.mvGameStates);  return *this; }
   ~GameStateMachine(){}

    void pushState(std::unique_ptr<GameState> pState);
    void changeState(std::unique_ptr<GameState> pState);
    void popState();

    void update(Game& game);
    void render();
    void cleanAndExit();
};
```

And instance of `GameStatesMachine` is used by `Game` class to update game. As you can see neither `GameStates` nor `GameStatesMachine` has members too fancy, just a couple of integers and some boolean. 
I use VS 2019 and the program does not compile and throws compilation error `c2280` pointing to the `GameStates` vector of `GameStateMachine`. I have read Microsoft documentation about it as well as several posts in StackExchange. As read, `unique_ptr` can not be copied and a `move constructor` must be implemented in order to do it and to avoid the compiler generates one itself and mark it as `delete`. So i have implemented `move constructor` in `GameState` base class and all inherited states classes. Nothing works. I implemented move constructor also in `GameStateMachine` with the same result. 
But if i change `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` the error vanishes and all compiles and works as expected. I want to use `unique_ptr` because i think the states are  going to be owned only by `Game`class, so why waste memory using a `shared_ptr`?. Am i wrong?

Comment: If you need help with the errors your `std::unique_ptr` usage generates, that's the version of the code you should share.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 thanks for the advice :). Done it.

Comment: And what's the specific compiler error and where does that happen?

Comment: The error is : `C++ Compiler Error C2280 "attempting to reference a deleted function"` and also prints this as a message : `See the reference to the creation of a template class instance "std :: vector <std :: unique_ptr <GameState, std :: default_delete <GameState>>, std :: allocator <std :: unique_ptr <GameState>`

Comment: Try to put the definition of your destructors in the cpp instead of the header...

Comment: @Vaillancourt thanks for answer :). I have put the definition of the related classes (Game, GameStateMachine, and all the states) in the .cpp but still happens :(

Comment: Could you add the part of your code that gives you the error C2280? I tried to compile what you have here and it works. (I had to add bodies to some of the methods)

Comment: @Heckel That is the part of the error, GameStateMachine.h . The compiler says that `GameState is not defined` in GameStateMachine class and `can´t delete an incomplete type`, but its header is included in GameStateMachine.cpp.

Comment: The compiler points to line 6 of `GameStateMachine.h` where `class GameState` is declared, but no header included. `GameState.h` is included in `GameStateMachine.cpp`

Comment: Change PushState and ChangeState to receive either r-value reference or const l-value reference.

Comment: Could you also try to move all of your functions defined in the headers in the cpp?

Comment: @Rish But `GameState` is an abstract class. Can i do references of an abstract class?

Comment: Yes. But you’re not doing a reference to an abstract class, but a reference to an unique_ptr.

Comment: @Rish Unfortunately it did not work. After a bit of research (sorry for the delay by the way)  i found the solution: as Vaillancourt suggest, move the definition of the destructor of `GameStateMachine`to the cpp file... and also the constructor. Within that file, where the `include"GameState.h"` is, the compiler did not complaint about the incomplete type of 'GameState' present in the `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>>mvGameStates`.